# Segmentation fault in C when trying to import header file and use it

Tags: c

When trying to compile my program in C I get a segfault for some reason I have tried to find out.

**This is my main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"

int main()
{   
    printf("My name is %s and is %s\n", NAME, AGE);
    return 0;
}
```

**main.h:**

```
#define AGE 30
#define NAME "Doelal"
```

Trying to compile with this:

```
gcc main.c -o main
```

And when I run it I get **Segmentation fault**.

Comment: `"My name is %s and is %s\n"` --> `"My name is %s and is %d\n"`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: OMG... thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you invoked undefined behaviour when you supplied AGE macro to printf. The format string in your code expects a string argument, but in reality your AGE macro is an integer constant literal.

You've got 2 options: either change format string from

```
"My name is %s and is %s\n"
```

to

```
"My name is %s and is %d\n"
```

or change your AGE macro from

```
#define AGE 30
```

to

```
#define AGE "30"
```

Answer (score 2):

To understand what is going on, do manual substitution the way the preprocessor does:

```
printf("My name is %s and is %s\n", NAME, AGE);
```

becomes

```
printf("My name is %s and is %s\n", "Doelal", 30);
```

Now match the `%` specifiers in the format string to the parameters. Do you see a mismatch in printing a number `30` with a `%s` format specifier?

You can fix it by providing the proper `%d` format specifier for the age:

```
"My name is %s and is %d\n"
//                     ^
```